# Dynamic hashed link in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

OK, so I have this code in the server side:

```
@app.route('/physical_graph') 
@login_required 
def physical_graph():
    # Some code
    return generate_graph_view()
```

If we click on the circular icon, we will get the link **/physical_graph#physical.circular:**

```
<a class="icon" href="/physical_graph#physical.circular">
    <img src="{{url_for('static',filename='images/circular64x64.png')}}" 
         id="circular_icon" width="32" height="32" title="Circular layout"/>
</a>
```

My question is: how can I tell Flask what string is after the hash? I need this because the code in the comment depends on this string. I tried with stating the app.route as:

```
@app.route('/physical_graph#<some_string>')
```

but without success - it gives me Error 404.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You can't # is left at the client side, why are you using hash? versus query params?  Or even better some rest sytax `/graph/physical.circle`

Comment: I need hash because I am ajax-ifying the application, so once I click some icon - to send and retrieve data asynchronously. So far it is /graph/physical.circle, but this loads the whole new page, that's why I need hash. So, it's not possible to do it this way with the hash link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you ajaxify it you need to pass physical.circle to the server.  First is just a comment on the use of `icon:`

```
<!-- notice i change from icon -> graphIcon icon is too general  -->
<!--a stylist would be angry at you for using icon -->
<a class="graphIcon" href="/physical_graph#physical.circular"> .. </a>
```

---

You have some options first would be to pass it in the data attribute, this would be placed somewhere in javascript (that only gets executed once).

```
jQuery("#circular_icon").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
         url:'/physical_graph', 
         data:{
               'graph_type': 'physical_graph.circular'
         },
         'success':function(data){
             //your function goes here. 
         }
   })
} );
```

---

```
@app.route('/physical_graph') 
@login_required 
def physical_graph():
  _type = request.args.get('graph_type')
```

Comment: Tnx, for the tip, but I am beginner and I want to ask you if you can please tell me where to put this code and how can I access this in the server side code?

Comment: Nope, when I do **print _type**, it gives me 'None'. I guess it gives me an empty string, so this code doesn't return me anything. Any other ideas how I can solve this? (BTW, you have some errors in the parenthesis in the ajax code, I tried with fixed parenthesis)

Comment: Didn't specify, so I guess 'GET'. Should I try with 'POST'?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26872/discussion-between-belphegor-and-nix)